# URL changing Script for amazon not working

Tags: javascript, url, greasemonkey

Im trying to write a little greasemonkey script that allows me to change the url with a little select box in the bottom right. I want to be able to switch between the different amazon markets (by replacing the domain with .it .es or whatever).

using http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0080K4K76/ ans an example

However it's not working correctly. The onchange doesn't seem to call the changer function.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           amazon__article_changer
// @namespace      wtf
// @include        *amazon*
// ==/UserScript==
function changer(end){
    var url = window.location.href;
    var nurl = "http://www.amazon."+ end + url.slice(url.indexOf("/gp/"), url.length);
    window.location.href = nurl;
}

box = window.document.createElement('div')
box.innerHTML = "<html><head><title></title></head><body><select onchange='changer(this.value)'><option value='de'>DE</option><option     value='co.uk'>UK</option><option value='fr'>FR</option><option value='es'>ES</option><option value='it'>IT</option></select></body></html>";
box.style.position = "fixed";
box.style.right = "0px";
box.style.bottom = "0px";
window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(box);
```

Answer (score -1):

Made it work, im sure this can be done a lot easier tho

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           amazon__article_changer
// @namespace      wtf
// @include        *mazon*
// ==/UserScript==
function changer(end){
    var url = window.location.href;
    var nurl = "http://www.amazon."+ end + url.slice(url.indexOf("/gp/"), url.length);
    window.location.href = nurl;
}

box = window.document.createElement('div');
box.innerHTML = "<html><head><title></title></head><body><select     onChange='changer(this.value)'><option></option><option value='de'>DE</option><option value='co.uk'>UK</option><option value='fr'>FR</option><option value='es'>ES</option><option value='it'>IT</option></select></body></html>";
box.style.position = "fixed";
box.style.right = "0px";
box.style.bottom = "0px";

sc = window.document.createElement('script');
sc.type = "text/javascript";
sc.innerHTML = "function changer(end){var url = window.location.href;var nurl = 'http://www.amazon.'+ end + url.slice(url.indexOf('/gp/'), url.length);window.location.href = nurl;}";

window.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(sc);
window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(box);
```